Experimental evidence of AC currents in a DC voltage
Ashcroft and Mermin page 225 suggests that because of the periodic nature of velocity in reciprocal space even a DC current will cause an oscillatory motion of the electrons. However, it is also said that impurities and collisions in the material forbid this effect. My questions is have we ever observed this effect experimentally in a very pure substance?

Why would a DC voltage source induce a AC current.You only get harmonics in the transient response but in the steady state response you only have DC current.

It is a quantum effect due to the periodic nature of the Brillouin zone
